# Python: ValueError raised when parsing a datetime string

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following `ValueError` is being raised while running the following code. The date is passed as a string from an another component, where I need to strip out the time.

```
ValueError: time data '2022-03-24T14:02:24.6413975' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'
```

The code:

```
from datetime import datetime
date='2022-03-24T14:02:24.6413975'
time = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f")
if time > '09:30' :
  print("do some thing")
```

Comment: Read the message carefully, and compare the expected format to the format of your datetime.

Comment: @S3DEV sorry but the format looks correct only rite? year-month-date hours::mintues:seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import datetime
date='2022-03-24T14:02:24.6413975'
time = date.split('T')[1].split(':')
time = datetime.time(int(time[0]), int(time[1]), int(time[2].split('.')[0]), int(time[2].split('.')[1][:6]))
if time > datetime.time(9, 30) :
    print("do some thing")
```

Output:

```
do some thing
```

This just takes `date`, splits it `T`, splits the second part of the resulting string at every `:`, and passes all of them to `datetime.time`. The last two arguments to `datetime.time` have to be split a the decimal to get the microseconds, and the last one has to be shortened because of the limit on how long `datetime` allows microseconds to be.

Comment: getting the below error                                                                                                                 time = datetime.time(int(time[0]), int(time[1]), int(time[2].split('.')[0]),
TypeError: descriptor 'time' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Comment: Did you make sure you imported `datetime` like `import datetime` and not `from datetime import datetime`?

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: String parsing should not be used (if at all possible) when working with dates. There are built-in functions to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue you're facing is the datetime format, as explained by the error message.

- The `.%f` formatter can only accept six decimal places.
- The `T` is missing from the format string.
- There is a comma before the `%f` formatter, where there should be a full stop.

Therefore, this is the formatting string you need:

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Additionally, `time` can be parsed from a `datetime` object simply by calling the `.time()` function as follows.  **String parsing should not be used**, if at all possible.

```
time = dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
```

Next, the `if` statement should compare `datetime` object to `datetime` object, as:

```
if time > dt.time(9,30):
    ...
```

---

Therefore, the complete solution is as follows:

```
import datetime as dt

# Fractional seconds reduced to 6 decimal places.
date = '2022-03-24T14:02:24.641397'  
# Use the .time() function to extract the time.
time = dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').time()
# Compare datetime object to datetime object.
if time > dt.time(9,30):
    print('Do some stuff ...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help:

```
def stripTime():
    date='2022-03-24T14:02:24.6413975'
    date=date.split('T')
    print(date[1])
stripTime()
```

Output:

```
14:02:24.6413975
```

Comment: This does not work for comparing dates though. You get a `str` but not a `datetime.time`

Comment: String parsing should *not* be used (if at all possible) when working with dates. There are built-in functions to help with this.